# Telegram User Adder

Tags: telegram-bot, telethon

Hi recently I made telegram scrapper that scrap users from telegram groups.
Now I am trying make user adder to it.

```
#!/bin/env python3
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetDialogsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerEmpty, InputPeerChannel, InputPeerUser
from telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist import PeerFloodError, UserPrivacyRestrictedError
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import InviteToChannelRequest
import configparser
import os, sys
import csv
import traceback
import time
import random

re="\033[1;31m"
gr="\033[1;32m"
cy="\033[1;36m"

def banner():
    print(f"""
  _____   __  ____ ____  ____   ___ ____    _____   __  ____ ____  ____   ___ ____      
                                                                    
 .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------.
| .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. |
| |      __      | || |  ________    | || |  ________    | || |  _________   | || |  _______     | |
| |     /  \     | || | |_   ___ `.  | || | |_   ___ `.  | || | |_   ___  |  | || | |_   __ \    | |
| |    / /\ \    | || |   | |   `. \ | || |   | |   `. \ | || |   | |_  \_|  | || |   | |__) |   | |
| |   / ____ \   | || |   | |    | | | || |   | |    | | | || |   |  _|  _   | || |   |  __ /    | |
| | _/ /    \ \_ | || |  _| |___.' / | || |  _| |___.' / | || |  _| |___/ |  | || |  _| |  \ \_  | |
| ||____|  |____|| || | |________.'  | || | |________.'  | || | |_________|  | || | |____| |___| | |
| |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | |
| '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' |
 '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'    
  _____   __  ____ ____  ____   ___ ____    _____   __  ____ ____  ____   ___ ____  
            version : 2.0
        """)

cpass = configparser.RawConfigParser()
cpass.read('config.data')

try:
    api_id = cpass['cred']['id']
    api_hash = cpass['cred']['hash']
    phone = cpass['cred']['phone']
    client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)
except KeyError:
    os.system('clear')
    banner()
    print(re+"[!] run python3 setup.py first !!\n")
    sys.exit(1)

client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone)
    os.system('clear')
    banner()
    client.sign_in(phone, input(gr+'[+] Enter the code: '+re))
 
os.system('clear')
banner()
input_file = sys.argv[1]
users = []
with open(input_file, encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    rows = csv.reader(f,delimiter=",",lineterminator="\n")
    next(rows, None)
    for row in rows:
        user = {}
        user['username'] = row[0]
        user['id'] = int(row[1])
        user['access_hash'] = int(row[2])
        user['name'] = row[3]
        users.append(user)
 
chats = []
last_date = None
chunk_size = 200
groups=[]
 
result = client(GetDialogsRequest(
             offset_date=last_date,
             offset_id=0,
             offset_peer=InputPeerEmpty(),
             limit=chunk_size,
             hash = 0
         ))
chats.extend(result.chats)
 
for chat in chats:
    try:
        if chat.megagroup== False:
            groups.append(chat)
    except:
        continue
 
i=0
for group in groups:
    print(gr+'['+cy+str(i)+gr+']'+cy+' - '+group.title)
    i+=1

print(gr+'[+] Choose a group to add members')
g_index = input(gr+"[+] Enter a Number : "+re)
target_group=groups[int(g_index)]
 
target_group_entity = InputPeerChannel(target_group.id,target_group.access_hash)
 
print(gr+"[1] add member by user ID\n[2] add member by username ")
mode = int(input(gr+"Input : "+re)) 
n = 0
 
for user in users:
    n += 1
    if n % 50 == 0:
        time.sleep(1)
        try:
            print ("Adding {}".format(user['id']))
            if mode == 1:
                if user['username'] == "":
                    continue
                user_to_add = client.get_input_entity(user['username'])
            elif mode == 2:
                user_to_add = InputPeerUser(user['id'], user['access_hash'])
            else:
                sys.exit(re+"[!] Invalid Mode Selected. Please Try Again.")
            client(InviteToChannelRequest(target_group_entity,[user_to_add]))
            print(gr+"[+] Waiting for 2-10 Seconds...")
            time.sleep(random.randrange(2, 10))
        except FloodWaitError:
            print(re+"[!] Getting Flood Error from telegram. \n[!] Script is stopping now. \n[!] Please try again after some time.")
        except UserPrivacyRestrictedError:
            print(re+"[!] The user's privacy settings do not allow you to do this. Skipping.")
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
            print(re+"[!] Unexpected Error")
            continue
```

It works but partly I can hardly add 1-10 user at a time and I shows errors some of adding proccess
Kindly I tried most thing command says it needs much time but timer doesnt seem effect on it even I add some.Any suggestions any helps ?

```
Adding 1456428294
[!] Getting FloodWaitError from telegram.
[!] Script is stopping now.
[!] Please try again after some time.
```

Answer (score 0):

> FloodWaitError (420)

**the same request was repeated many times. Must wait .seconds (you can access this attribute). For example:**

```
from telethon import errors

try:
    messages = await client.get_messages(chat)
    print(messages[0].text)
except errors.FloodWaitError as e:
    print('Have to sleep', e.seconds, 'seconds')
    time.sleep(e.seconds)
```

Read the documentation:
https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/concepts/errors.html